# Spring boot java.net.SocketTimeoutException while uploading large files

Tags: java, spring-boot, tomcat, file-upload, large-files

I can upload files to the server in my application, I use angular in the front-end I'm using this library to upload files [ng2-file-upload](https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-file-upload), and I'm using Spring boot in the backend, for the moment it works fine for files up to 1GB, however for even bigger files I got this exeception while uploading :

```
Caused by: java.io.IOException: org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadBase$IOFileUploadException: Processing of multipart/form-data request failed. null
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.parseParts(Request.java:2932) ~[catalina.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.parseParameters(Request.java:3232) ~[catalina.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.getParameter(Request.java:1137) ~[catalina.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade.getParameter(RequestFacade.java:381) ~[catalina.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:75) ~[spring-web-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    ... 35 more
Caused by: org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadBase$IOFileUploadException: Processing of multipart/form-data request failed. null
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadBase.parseRequest(FileUploadBase.java:297) ~[tomcat-coyote.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.parseParts(Request.java:2884) ~[catalina.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.parseParameters(Request.java:3232) ~[catalina.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.getParameter(Request.java:1137) ~[catalina.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade.getParameter(RequestFacade.java:381) ~[catalina.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:75) ~[spring-web-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    ... 35 more
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioBlockingSelector.read(NioBlockingSelector.java:201) ~[tomcat-coyote.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.read(NioSelectorPool.java:235) ~[tomcat-coyote.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.read(NioSelectorPool.java:216) ~[tomcat-coyote.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$NioSocketWrapper.fillReadBuffer(NioEndpoint.java:1250) ~[tomcat-coyote.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEnd

point$NioSocketWrapper.read(NioEndpoint.java:1193) ~[tomcat-coyote.jar:8.5.31]
```

It's seems that while uploading the server recieved a null request but I'm not sure, can anybody explain this error?

Comment: Try to set `server.connection-timeout=-1` property in application.properties and check if the error appears (-1 means infinite timeout)

Comment: I tried it but same error, thanks though.

Comment: Hmmm ... Maybe try check it how it behave on standalone tomcat ?

Comment: I redeployed today and it works, strange I'm pretty sure it didn't work yesterday, maybe it takes sometimes before giving effects, anyway can you add it as an answer maybe it can help somebody else.

Comment: Pretty sure `server.connection-timeout` only applies to the connection phase. As long as a connection is made within that time, you're good. Other timeouts that might be important here would be read/write timeouts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To invastigate this issue you can do following:
1. Add `server.connection-timeout=-1` property to application.properties and check if the error appears (-1 means infinite timeout)
2. Try to deploy war on standalone tomcat (as far as i know sometimes it behave diffrent that embedded into springboot)

Answer (score 0):

in our case, changing `application.properties` on spring  had no effect, the solution was changing tomcat `server.xml` config, increasing `connectionTimeout` from 20000 (20 secs):

```
 <Connector connectionTimeout="20000" port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1" redirectPort="8443"/>
```