# HTTP Status 500 – Internal Server Error while uploading multipart/form-data

Tags: ajax, apache, spring-mvc, multipartform-data, tomcat9

I am getting error when i uploading 20 MB Size of csv file in Spring MVC by using CommonsMultipartResolver library. I have done following setting in Config File  :

```
@Bean(name = "filterMultipartResolver")
public CommonsMultipartResolver multipartResolver() throws IOException {
    logger.info("CommonsMultipartResolver Set!!");
    CommonsMultipartResolver multipartResolver = new CommonsMultipartResolver();
    multipartResolver.setMaxInMemorySize(600 * 1024 * 1024);
    multipartResolver.setMaxUploadSizePerFile(100*1024 * 1024);
    multipartResolver.setMaxUploadSize(600 * 1024 * 1024);
    return multipartResolver;
}
```

Controller :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/FileUploadModel", method = { RequestMethod.POST, RequestMethod.GET })
public @ResponseBody String fileuploadInObjectStorage(@RequestParam(value = "jobType", required = false) String jobType,
        @RequestParam(value = "scheduleRule", required = false) String scheduleRule,
        @RequestParam(value = "automationRule", required = false) String automationRule,
        @RequestParam(value = "importDateFormat", required = true) String importDateFormat,
        @RequestParam(value = "file", required = false) MultipartFile[] multiFile1,
        @RequestParam(value = "companyName2", required = true) String company, 
        @RequestParam(value = "className2", required = true) String className,
        HttpServletRequest request,HttpSession session) throws Exception {...}
```

Ajax Call:

```
$.ajax({
                    url: contextPath+'/FileUploadModel',
                    type: "POST",
                    data: formData,
                    enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
                    processData: false,
                    contentType: false,
                    timeout:0,
                    beforeSend: function() {
                        $("#scheduleRuleDiv,#automationRuleDiv,#JSDateFormatDiv,#JSUploadfileDiv,#uploadGobtnDiv,#uploadFiles").hide();

                        $.blockUI({
                            fadeIn: 1000,
                            message:msg1
                        });

                    },
```

But I am not understanding what is issue. I tried to set up size and setting header also enctype="multipart/form-data", but yet not resolved.

Given below are error:

```
HTTP Status 500 – Internal Server Error
```

Type Exception Report

Message Could not parse multipart servlet request; nested exception is org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadBase$IOFileUploadException: Processing of multipart/form-data request failed. java.net.SocketTimeoutException

Description The server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request.

Exception

org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartException: Could not parse multipart servlet request; nested exception is org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadBase$IOFileUploadException: Processing of multipart/form-data request failed. java.net.SocketTimeoutException
org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver.parseRequest(CommonsMultipartResolver.java:165)
org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver.resolveMultipart(CommonsMultipartResolver.java:142)
org.springframework.web.multipart.support.MultipartFilter.doFilterInternal(MultipartFilter.java:112)
org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
Root Cause

org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadBase$IOFileUploadException: Processing of multipart/form-data request failed. java.net.SocketTimeoutException
org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadBase.parseRequest(FileUploadBase.java:351)
org.apache.commons.fileupload.servlet.ServletFileUpload.parseRequest(ServletFileUpload.java:115)
org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver.parseRequest(CommonsMultipartResolver.java:158)
org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver.resolveMultipart(CommonsMultipartResolver.java:142)
org.springframework.web.multipart.support.MultipartFilter.doFilterInternal(MultipartFilter.java:112)
org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
Root Cause

org.apache.catalina.connector.ClientAbortException: java.net.SocketTimeoutException
org.apache.catalina.connector.InputBuffer.realReadBytes(InputBuffer.java:322)
org.apache.catalina.connector.InputBuffer.checkByteBufferEof(InputBuffer.java:600)
org.apache.catalina.connector.InputBuffer.read(InputBuffer.java:340)
org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteInputStream.read(CoyoteInputStream.java:132)
java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:133)
org.apache.commons.fileupload.util.LimitedInputStream.read(LimitedInputStream.java:134)
org.apache.commons.fileupload.MultipartStream$ItemInputStream.makeAvailable(MultipartStream.java:999)
org.apache.commons.fileupload.MultipartStream$ItemInputStream.read(MultipartStream.java:903)
java.io.InputStream.read(InputStream.java:101)
org.apache.commons.fileupload.util.Streams.copy(Streams.java:100)
org.apache.commons.fileupload.util.Streams.copy(Streams.java:70)
org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadBase.parseRequest(FileUploadBase.java:347)
org.apache.commons.fileupload.servlet.ServletFileUpload.parseRequest(ServletFileUpload.java:115)
org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver.parseRequest(CommonsMultipartResolver.java:158)
org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver.resolveMultipart(CommonsMultipartResolver.java:142)
org.springframework.web.multipart.support.MultipartFilter.doFilterInternal(MultipartFilter.java:112)
org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
Root Cause

java.net.SocketTimeoutException
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$NioSocketWrapper.fillReadBuffer(NioEndpoint.java:1290)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$NioSocketWrapper.read(NioEndpoint.java:1207)
org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer.fill(Http11InputBuffer.java:805)
org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer.access$300(Http11InputBuffer.java:42)
org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer$SocketInputBuffer.doRead(Http11InputBuffer.java:1172)
org.apache.coyote.http11.filters.IdentityInputFilter.doRead(IdentityInputFilter.java:101)
org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer.doRead(Http11InputBuffer.java:249)
org.apache.coyote.Request.doRead(Request.java:640)
org.apache.catalina.connector.InputBuffer.realReadBytes(InputBuffer.java:317)
org.apache.catalina.connector.InputBuffer.checkByteBufferEof(InputBuffer.java:600)
org.apache.catalina.connector.InputBuffer.read(InputBuffer.java:340)
org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteInputStream.read(CoyoteInputStream.java:132)
java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:133)
org.apache.commons.fileupload.util.LimitedInputStream.read(LimitedInputStream.java:134)
org.apache.commons.fileupload.MultipartStream$ItemInputStream.makeAvailable(MultipartStream.java:999)
org.apache.commons.fileupload.MultipartStream$ItemInputStream.read(MultipartStream.java:903)
java.io.InputStream.read(InputStream.java:101)
org.apache.commons.fileupload.util.Streams.copy(Streams.java:100)
org.apache.commons.fileupload.util.Streams.copy(Streams.java:70)
org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadBase.parseRequest(FileUploadBase.java:347)
org.apache.commons.fileupload.servlet.ServletFileUpload.parseRequest(ServletFileUpload.java:115)
org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver.parseRequest(CommonsMultipartResolver.java:158)
org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver.resolveMultipart(CommonsMultipartResolver.java:142)
org.springframework.web.multipart.support.MultipartFilter.doFilterInternal(MultipartFilter.java:112)
org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
Note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the server logs.

Apache Tomcat/9.0.50

NOTE : same code is working fine on IBM Liberty server for 99mb file.

Comment: Double-check endpoints: **request failed. java.net.SocketTimeoutException**

Answer (score 0):

you can see SocketTimeOut in tomcat's error log.

maybe increasing server's connectionTimeout resolve the error.

check this [Spring boot java.net.SocketTimeoutException while uploading large files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52702304/spring-boot-java-net-sockettimeoutexception-while-uploading-large-files)

Comment: Thanks for response. But we are using the spring mvc and we can not edit server.xml as we are pulling image of tomcat from dockerhub.